# Tkinter Button style (relief) not showing properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, tkinter

I tried to use "relief" option when creating buttons in tkinter, but the style of buttons are not showing properly.

Here is a link to the website of info I found. There is a picture of expected result on that website.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_relief.htm

My code:

```
from tkinter import *
# from tkinter.ttk import *


root = Tk()
root_width, root_height = 200, 500
root.geometry("{}x{}".format(root_width, root_height))

b1 = Button(root, text="button", relief=FLAT)
b2 = Button(root, text="button", relief=RAISED)
b3 = Button(root, text="button", relief=SUNKEN)
b4 = Button(root, text="button", relief=GROOVE)
b5 = Button(root, text="button", relief=RIDGE)

b1.pack()
b2.pack()
b3.pack()
b4.pack()
b5.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

All the buttons appear on the screen look exactly the same.  [my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQ0Sr.png)

Wondering why this happens, is there a way I can fix it or other methods that allow me to customize the button widget.

I tried to use ttk, but the following error occurred

```
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-relief"
```

I am currently running Python3, in PyCharm, on MacBook Pro with macOS Sierra 10.12 installed.

Thanks!

Comment: I just ran the code on my system (Win10, Python3) and it works fine. I think this is not a problem with the code itself. Have you tried running it from the command-line? Edit: [link](http://imgur.com/a/6JS90)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running on OSX, and that OS has strict guidelines for the appearance of buttons. You can't change the relief on buttons on OSX.

Comment: So is there a way I can change the layout/appearance of buttons on OSX?

Comment: @terryy: layout? Yes. Appearance? No. Though, you can create custom buttons using images, or with labels, or with the canvas widget.

Comment: so for canvas or labels, how do I make it a button? In my previous project, I use canvas for everything and bind mouse press to functions. In that function, I find the coordinate of the mouse and check if it is on a canvas element or not. That got really complicated. Is there an easier way to put a label or canvas in button mode?