# Tkinter button relief on OSX not changing until I switch windows

Tags: python, macos, button, tkinter

I am designing a gui with Tkinter and specific buttons are misbehaving. The main app window includes a button to connect to a machine. The button command works fine, as the connection is successful, but the button does not change relief or color when clicked. If I click out of the app (or create a new window via one of the buttons inside the app), then click back to the main window, the button looks exactly as intended. It is only on startup that the button decides to be lazy.

Once the machine is connected, it brings up more buttons that look and operate correctly, it is only the first button that is a problem. Below are some pictures of the buttons and how they look before and after connecting.

[Connect button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gc3WE.png)

[New buttons after connecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eR8jM.png)

If it helps, I am using OSX 10.10 with updated Python 3.6.5(64-bit for OSX <s>10.6+</s> 10.9+),<s>, as well as ActiveTcl version 8.5.18.0</s>.

The following code brings up a test button with the same problem.

```
import tkinter as tk

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Button Test')

    button = tk.Button(root, text = 'test me', padx= '20', pady = '20')
    button.grid()

    root.mainloop()
```

EDIT: I have searched around and found that some people fixed issues similar to this by updating Python/Tcl packages, but my issue seems to be persistent.

EDIT2: I tried changing the type from tk.Button() to tk.ttk.Button() and this seems to fix the visual bug, but it draws a grey border around the new button due to the default "style" option. That is a separate issue however and others have asked how to fix it on here.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Do not link code or images outside of stack overflow. Instead insert the image or code in your question.

Comment: @Mike-SMT I cannot embed images due to the age of my account.

Comment: What about the code? Please read the link Bryan has provided and then provide a MCVE.

Comment: @Mike-SMT Code added, the small box appears but the button does not appear show any interaction with the mouse until I change to a new window and back

Comment: One thing I see off the bat is: `if __name__ = '__main__':` should be `if __name__ == '__main__':`. There are several typos and and incorrect words here. Is this your code or just an example you typed up just now.

Comment: @Mike-SMT This is just an example, but when I do a simple button like this it has the same issue as my main project.

Comment: Please correct your `if __name__ = '__main__':` statement. This is still wrong and needs to be `if __name__ == '__main__':`. That said I do not see the same issue you are having. My button works without issues.

Comment: And you are using mac? I've read the mac buttons can be more strict than on windows or linux.

Answer (score 1):

I've been doing some research on this too, and apparently Mac OSX doesn't support background color for buttons or the relief styles. You can find it [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45027628/tkinter-button-style-relief-not-showing-properly).

However, there is a module I've found that allows for more customization for OSX. You can find IT [here.](https://pypi.org/project/tkmacosx/)

Answer (score 0):

I see several typos here.

Change:

```
import tkinter as tk

if __name__ = '__main__': # needs to be == not =.
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Button Test')
    # test= should be text=. remove command if you are not using it.
    # typo in padx. padx '20; should be padx='20'
    button = tk.Button(root, test = 'test me', command = None, padx '20;, pady = '20')
    button.grid()

    root.mainloop()
```

To this:

```
import tkinter as tk

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Button Test')

    button = tk.Button(root, text='test me', padx='20', pady='20')
    button.grid()

    root.mainloop()
```